# Debug PHP running on guest virtual box

Tags: php, xdebug

I have PHP and apache running on Ubuntu which is running in Virtual Box. From host OS I am trying to run debugger.

I am using netbeans as a IDE which runs on host os. in Tools->Options->PHP->Debugging I set port 9000.

Port 9000 is opened in firewall (I verified that by running apache on host on port 9000 - it was accessible from guest)

Please correct me if I am wrong but it looks like debugger is passive in PHP so the netbeans suppose to listen on 9000 for incoming connection from xdebug?

Can I specify on which interface netbeans is listening for xdebug?
How can I troubleshoot xdebug connection between runtime and netbeans?

Comment: Are you setting the IDE/debug session key correctly in Netbeans and in your xdebug conf? Posting your xdebug config may be useful. I believe you are correct in that Netbeans should listen on 9000 - but PHP/xdebug will only try to connect if you are providing the correct IDE/session key value.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your input. Stupidly enough it worked after restarting netbeans :(